# Search for users that have a created date of greater than 14 days ago, then update expired field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here are my requirements using mongoose/node -

Users can only login to the system if they were created within 14 past. If a user is trying to login and they are at 14 days, they are no longer valid and need to ask an admin for an extension.

What I want to do (whether this is right or not) is when getting all users, do a search for those that were created 14 days or more ago and set an expired field to true (I can check this when I authenticate. I also want this to show a separate table in the UI that only shows expired users).

I initially thought setting 'expires' in the createdDate field would work, but that deletes the record, which I don't want.

Here is my UserSchema and my current getAllUsers function. I don't have anything in there to try and figure this out yet.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    role: {type: String, default: 'user' },
    hashedPassword: String,
    provider: String,
    salt: String,
    assignedFile: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    expired: Boolean
});

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  User.find({}, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, users) {
    console.log(users)
    if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.status(200).json(users);
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you want to do the check when the user tries to login? i.e., user attempts to login, you query database with user id and if the user is 14 days over then you add the expired field? or do you want a service that's running to check all users everyday and add the expired field to those it applies to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter on dates you will need [$lt](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt) or [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte). You also need to make your filter date dynamically. For example:

```
var now = new Date();
// Set the date 14 days in the past
now = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate()-14));
```

This returns all the users who have not logged in for more than 14 days:

```
User.find({createdDate: {$lte: now}}, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, users) {
    console.log(users);
    if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).json(users);
});
```

If you want to update `expired` Boolean, you will need to update multiple documents like this:

```
// $set allows you to update one or more values without updating the whole document
// multi: true allows you to update multiple documents at the same time
User.update({createdDate: {$lte: now}}, {$set: {expired: true}}, {multi: true}).exec(function (err, users) {
    console.log(users);
    if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).json(users);
});
```

The above function only updates the documents. If you want to run this function automatically every day, you will need to "call" this function in a cronjob.

Comment: You beat me to it. Nicely answered!

Comment: Thank you! This answer was perfect!